# I am getting error when i use headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +this.AuthToken);

Tags: php, angular

> When i am hiding authorization header it's working fine, but When i am
>   using Authorization header i am getting error.Below is my angular 2
>   code:

```
  getinfo() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var headers = new Headers();
            this.loadUserCredentials();
            console.log(this.AuthToken);
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +this.AuthToken);
            //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            this.http.get('http://ip/ramu/api/index.php?action=getUserInfo', {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
                if(data.json().success)
                    resolve(data.json());
                else
                    resolve(false);
            });
        })
    }
```

> Back end i am using php. i have used headers in php page given below

```
header("access-control-allow-origin: *"); header('content-type:
application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

> Below error i am getting

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip/ramu/api/index.php?action=getUserInfo. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

> What i have to do in back end to allow authorization based on token or
>   i need to do add any angular code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most non-standard headers require whitelisting (just like the origin) in the CORS pre-flight response so on the backend:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");
```

Comment: It's working fine. when i am added below header on back-end.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");

Answer (score 0):

you can send headers like this to allow origin.

```html
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
?>
```